# 1.54 e-ink without driver PCB

Tags: arduino, spi, display, e-ink

I want to know if it is possible to use [this raw e-ink display](https://www.robotics.org.za/image/cache/catalog/waveshare/W12561/W12561-000-500x500.jpg)  with Arduino. Is it possible to directly connect cables from this ribbon cable to Arduino without any driver PCB and control it with 3 or 4 wire SPI? I was looking for some tutorials but I haven't found anything. In the future I would like to use it with nRF52832 BLE chip.  [the pinout of the display is on 6th page](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/77/1.54inch_e-Paper_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: that’s true. i forgot. i just posted the datasheet

Comment: DONT CROSS POST!

Comment: Not even closely compatible without an interface adapter

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I wouldn't call it "interface adapter", since interface is SPI and doesn't need an adapter. But it does require a lot of external components for power connections and I don't see how it can be done without any PCB.

Comment: Yes a video "adapter" !!  ( albeit low BW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is definitely possible to drive the display with a general purpose MCU.

Check the voltage levels depending on Arduino some are 3.3V ones and some are 5V.

Take care of the discrete stuff too!

From the data sheet:

[image]

Comment: thanks. i was thinking that i will just solder few wires to ribbon cable but now i understand that there must be lot of other components